# "Искать" и "Поиск" в хинтах расширенного поиска

Tags: предложение, локализация

Во всплывающих подсказках [расширенного поиска](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search) используются разные слова ("Поиск" или "Искать") для однотипных действий:

> "Поиск в метках (можно сразу в нескольких)"
>
> "Поиск точной формулировки (можно сразу нескольких)"
>
> "Искать в сообщениях пользователей"
>
> "Искать в собственных сообщениях"
>
> "Искать сообщения с 3 и более голосами"
>
> "Искать сообщения с рейтингом 0"
>
> "Искать вопросы минимум с 3 ответами"
>
> "Искать вопросы без ответов"
>
> "Искать только принятые ответы (yes)"
>   "Искать только непринятые ответы (no)"
>
> "Искать вопросы с принятым ответом (yes)"
>   "Искать вопросы без принятых ответов (no)"
>
> "Искать ответы на вопрос
>   (или используйте функцию «inquestion:this» на странице вопроса)"
>
> "Искать вопросы с числом просмотров 250 и больше"
>
> "Искать только в заголовках"
>
> "Искать только в текстовой части сообщений"
>
> "Искать ссылки или изображения в сообщениях"
>
> "Поиск вопросов, добавленных вами в избранное"
>
> "Поиск вопросов, добавленных в избранное пользователем 1234"
>
> "Поиск в закрытых вопросах (yes)
>    Поиск незакрытых вопросов (no)"
>
> "Поиск вопросов, которые были закрыты как копии (yes)
>   Поиск вопросов, которые не были закрыты как копии (no)"
>
> "Поиск перенесенных вопросов (yes)
>    Поиск неперенесенных вопросов (no)"
>
> "Искать общие сообщения (yes)
>    Искать сообщения, не являющиеся общими (no)"
>
> "Искать только вопросы"
>
> "Искать только ответы"

Так получилось, видимо, из-за того, что перевод был осуществлен разными людьми.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю использовать слово "Искать" во всех случаях.